# C++ - Why isn't this structure of diamond inheritance cause an ambiguity?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual-inheritance

I have scanned through dozens of multiple inheritance question but wasn't able to find an answer for this question.

I understand why this won't compile:

```
struct B{
    virtual void f(){
        printf("B");
    }
};

struct C1 : virtual B{
   void f() override{
        printf("C1");
    }
};

struct C2: virtual B{
    void f() override{
        printf("C2")
    }
};

struct D: C1,C2{
    
};
```

Because there is not way to determine which `f` should be in `B`'s vtable.

However, I was quite surprised to see that this code will compile:

```
struct B{
    virtual void f(){
        printf("B");
    }
};

struct C1 : virtual B{
   void f() override{
        printf("C1");
    }
};

struct C2: virtual B{

};

struct D: C1,C2{
    
};
```

My (wrong) intuition was that we still have two path from `D` to `B` and in each one the last place `f` is overridden is different - in one path it's in `C1` and in one path it's in `B`, but this does compile.

Why doesn't this cause an ambiguity?

Comment: My guess is that everything in `D` is in fact overridden once on each "level" of inheritance and since `B` doesn't have members, there is no "collision" for them either. But that is just a blind guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because C1::f1 overrides B::f1, it will be used in preference on any object that has a dynamic type of C1 or any subclass.

In the ambiguous case, While both C1::f1 and C2::f1 override B::f1, they do not override each other, so the ambiguity is between them -- the fact that they both override a common base function is irrelevant.